# After update from react-redux 5.0.7 to 6 connected components don't receive updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a working RN application written in TS with `react-redux 5.0.7` installed. If I update - connected components don't receive updates. From [their release notes](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases) I can see, that they started to use new context api. I have `react 16.5.0` which is higher than their minimal version. Does anyone have similar issues and maybe a workaround?

The not-working code is pretty much simple. I've already checked the state changing itself (it works), so the only interesting thing could be the connection itself. I do it like this:

```
const connected = connect(
    (state: AppState) => {
        return {
            partOfComponentState: state.someInnerState
        }
    },
    {
        // funcs
    }
)(MyContainerComponent)

export default connected
```

The wrapper of the root looks like this:

```
    return <Provider store={store}>
        <TabBar />
    </Provider>
```

And store:

```
const store = createStore(
    mainReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is that syntax `(state: AppState)`, flow?

Comment: @Sagivb.g, ts, updated the question

Comment: Can you double-check exactly which versions of React and ReactDOM you have, and in particular, if they match each other?

Comment: @markerikson, I don't have ReactDOM as I understand, because it's React Native (am I wrong?)

react is `react@^16.5.0` resolved to `version "16.7.0"`